# OS X: How to create a user account with access to the applications that she has installed only

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, user-accounts

Till now, I've been the sole and proud owner of an iMac. I've always logged in as an administrator and I've also installed a bunch of software following the standard procedure of dragging and dropping it into the Applications folder.

This is about to change, as sharing it with a friend makes a lot of sense now that I only have time to use the computer in the mornings, and she can only use it at nights.

I thought this was going to be really easy: Just create a user account for her and that's all, I thought.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. When she logins into the computer using her username and password, she has access to the same applications I've installed. Even the same applications that I setup to automatically start when I login start for her when she does.

How can I setup a user that has only access to the applications that she has installed, but none of the ones installed by other users?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you copy any of your files into her home directory?

Answer (score 3):

Just create a folder `Applications` in your home directory. You can safely move just about anything that doesn't come with an installer, and even some that do.

---

Regarding automatically starting applications, those are usually configured in *System Preferences » Accounts » Login Items*. Make sure she doesn't have any entries there from your applications.

---

Using *Parental Controls* in the same preference pane, you can restrict what applications she can use.

[image]